# How would I make gun animations for guns with multiple swappable parts

Tags: animation

I would like to have weapon customization in my game but I can't figure out how to animate the parts of the gun so that they can be switched out.

Comment: This question is a little too broad to get a productive answer in this SE. It would be better to make an attempt, and then ask about, (and illustrate) the first specific problem you run into.

Answer (score 1):

Switching out parts isn't an animation issue. You would do that through code. You rig your weapon and create bones or sockets for attachments and then in game you program it so that the attachments you imported separately from the gun get snapped to the right bone or socket.